# Syntax error at token MZ using ilasm

Tags: winforms, assembly, strongname, ilasm

I have a prebuilt dll assembly that I am trying to use. It is a winforms library and when I reference it I can use it in the designer/code without error. When I run it I get:

> Assembly generation failed -- Referenced assembly 'YARTE' does not have a strong name

I decided to do the ildasm => ilasm round trip but I keep getting this error

```
C:\...\bin>ilasm /dll /key=mykey.snk YARTE.dll

Microsoft (R) .NET Framework IL Assembler.  Version 4.0.30319.17929
Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.
Assembling 'YARTE.dll'  to DLL --> 'YARTE.dll'
Source file is ANSI

YARTE.dll(1) : error : syntax error at token 'MZ' in: ZÉ
```

I'm not finding much help elsewhere but I don't think this is a rare problem.

Comment: You are trying to assemble a binary file!

Comment: I know this is an old post, but happend to me recently. I was using the dll file instead of an il file with ilasm.
ildasm => file.il

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why are you trying to compile the `yarte`  *DLL* file? `ilasm` should take an IL *source* file.

It's not really a round trip if you ignore the output of `ildasm` :-)

Comment: Turns out i did have IL as source the first time but had another command error. Then everytime after that I was using the .dll >_< I'm a noob, deleting this question

Comment: @CameronScully, I'd only delete it if you're relatively sure it won't help anyone else in the future. That's a judgement call on your part. Based on a cursory search, this isn't a _totally_ unique experience (http://forums.asp.net/t/1496257.aspx/2/10) so it may be worth leaving it alone since someone is likely to search for `"syntax error at token MZ"` and find this exact Q&A.